# How to use puppeteer in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, puppeteer

I made some code to **scrape** some information from an webpage using puppeteer and I wanted to use react to show the information. But when I tried to install the puppeteer package in the react app, I found that I can't install it. Did I make something wrong, or is it impossible to use puppeteer in react? And if is impossible, is there an alternative to implement puppeteer?

```
import React, {Component}  from 'react';
import './App.css';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      name:"Test"
   };
   }

   render(){
    return(
      <h1> {this.state.name} </h1>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

And I get this error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'ws' in 'C:\Users\zoica\Desktop\PupeteerTest\my-app\node_modules\puppeteer\lib'
```

Comment: Suggest you create a separate service to run puppeteer

Comment: And how do I access the data? Can you please give me some code, or more details?

Comment: By wrapping it in a function and returning a promise. Really don't think you want to import pupeteer into your front end app.Would be better to create a back end endpoint for it

Comment: Thanks! I will try this

Comment: Update! I tried this ,and it worked beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to import puppeteer like this:

`import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';`

Comment: and the same error? How do you invoke the puppeteer?

Comment: All the code that I tried is the one above ,and when I try "npm start" the error appears